# XSL changing spaces in a link to %20

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, xslt

I  need to change links that are automatically created by MOSS07 with spaces to include %20.

---

Example:

```
{$SafeLinkURL}
```

which would output https://stackoverflow.com/example of spaces

https://stackoverflow.com/example%20of%20spaces

---

If anyone can shed some light on this please do.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

The XSLT 2.0 function(s) Dimitrie mentioned are:

1. [`fn:encode-for-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-encode-for-uri)
2. [`fn:iri-to-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-iri-to-uri)
3. [`fn:escape-html-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-escape-html-uri)

See the links for detailed specification and examples. In your case (if you could've used a XSLT 2.0 processor) the `fn:iri-to-uri()` would've solved your problem.

But *none of these functions will not work in your current XSLT 1.0 environment*. So please see this post as a future reference for other people.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what exactly is asked for in this question.

**In case the problem is to replace all space characters in a given string with "%20", here is an XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link/text()[contains(., ' ')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="replace"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pTarget" select="' '"/>
  <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'%20'"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pTarget))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring-before($pText, $pTarget)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="replace">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
            "substring-after($pText, $pTarget)"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pTarget" select="$pTarget"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement"
            select="$pReplacement"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<link>http://stackoverflow.com/example of spaces</link>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<link>http://stackoverflow.com/example%20of%20spaces</link>
```

Comment: Not judging, but don't you think that tons of decode/encode-string extension functions would suit better? Things with urls usually tend to get more complex rather fast.

Comment: @Flack: Sure, but he seems to ask how to do this with XSLT. I think there is a standard XPath 2.0 function for exactly such URL encoding.

Comment: I've got point and you are right. But, I guess, additional link for EXSLT strings or similar will be still worth mentioning :)

Comment: @Flack: Thanks. He cannot use EXSLT because he is using MSXML inside Share Point.

Answer (score 0):

My input was

```
<a href="a/file name.pdf">
```

I wanted to handle this space, applied `encode(@href, 'UTF-8')` by adding `xmlns:u="java:java.net.URLEncoder"`

Output:

```
<a href="a%2Ffile+name.pdf">
```

The problem here is + instead of %20. So I replaced that using `replace($encoded-name, '[+]', '%20')`

Code that you want to copy:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" 
xmlns:u="java:java.net.URLEncoder"
>
<xsl:param name="encoded-name" select="u:encode(@href, 'UTF-8')"/>
<xsl:param name="final-name" select="replace($encoded-name, '[+]', '%20')"/>
```

Final output:

```
<a href="a%2Ffile%20name.pdf">
```